# React Native object child mapping inside parent map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-native, react-redux

Is it possible to mapping child object from parent map?

I have data like this:

```
[
 {
  "hdr_name": "A",
  "detail": [
    {
      "dtl_name": "Aaron Bennet"
    },
    {
      "dtl_name": "Ali Connors"
    }
  ]
 },
 {
  "hdr_name": "B",
  "detail": [
    {
      "dtl_name": "Bradley Horowitz"
    },
    {
      "dtl_name": "Brian Sweetland"
    },
  ]
 }
]
```

I want to show the header name and detail name, I got the header name using map

```
{this.props.selcheckSheet.data.map((item, index) => {
  return (
     <ListItem itemDivider key={index} >
      <Body>
       <Text>{item.hdr_name}</Text>
      </Body>                          
     </ListItem>

     //How to loop detail in item.detail?

})}
```

So, how to get the item.detail and render to ListItem?
I want to render view like this:
[image: React Native View]

Comment: I think [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) will be more useful to you, i will not suggest to use `map` if you have large number of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure, pretty similar on how you already done the parent:

```
{this.props.selcheckSheet.data.map((item, index) => {
  return (
     <ListItem itemDivider key={index} >
      <Body>
       <Text>{item.hdr_name}</Text>
      </Body>                          
     </ListItem>

     {item.detail.map((u,i) => 
        <ListItem itemDivider key={'' + index + i} >
          <Body>
            <Text>{u.dtl_name}</Text>
          </Body>                          
        </ListItem>
     )}

}))}
```

Comment: @AnandaBayuPutraYudhistira yep, one more bracket in the end, I updated the answer

Comment: I use <View> and </View> between the first ListItem and {childloop} and it's works now, thanks.